# Using YAML with Swig Templates

Tags: yaml, swig-template

Is there an equivalent to Assemble's integration of YAML for Swig?

Having to write `{% block title %}Title Here{% endblock %}` isn't as nice as:

```
---
title: Title Here
---
```

Any ideas on how to integrate YAML with Swig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assemble uses the [`yaml-frontmatter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml-front-matter) to read and strip off that little block of yaml at the start of each template.

You can integrate this directly into your own build toolchain:

- Gulp with [`gulp-front-matter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-front-matter)
- Grunt with [`grunt-matter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-matter) (from assemble)